# Problema al cargar imagenes con thymeleaft spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Estoy desarrollando mi pagina web con spring y thymeleaft y resulta que tengo el siguiente problema, no me cargan las imágenes que tengo metidas en el proyecto (son imágenes estaticas) si no que me sale el tipico cuadrado de que no la encuentra.

Mi codigo index.html es el siguiente:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Online Shopping</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css"/>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        /* Make the image fully responsive */
        .carousel-inner img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #columna{
            margin:10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header">...</div>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img th:src="@{'src/main/resources/static/images/roma.jpg'}" src="../static/images/roma.jpg" alt="Roma" width="1100" height="500"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img th:src="@{'/images/madrid.jpg'}" src="../static/images/madrid.jpg" alt="Madrid" width="1100" height="500"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img th:src="@{'/images/madrid.jpg'}"  src="../static/images/madrid.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <h1 th:text="${categoria.getNombre()}"></h1>

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-carousel">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="owl-item">
                <div class="col-*-2" th:each="prod: ${productos}" id="columna">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="" alt="producto" class="card-img-top"/>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 th:text="${prod.getNombre()}"></h3>
                            <h5>$<span class="text-center" th:text="${prod.getPrecio()}"></span></h5>
                            <p th:text="${prod.getId()}"></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer">...</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({

    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
}
    )})
</script>

</html>
```

Cabe destacar que en el código he puesto ambas formas de las cuales estoy intentando cargar mi código para ver si alguien da con la solución

Mi estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

Estoy usando spring version 1.5

Ya no se que mas probar y yo creo que esta siendo problema de las rutas.

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo hago referencia la las imagen en mi proyecto de esta manera

```
     <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="user dropdown-toggle" href="#" aria-expanded="true">
 <img th:src="@{/images/avatar.png}" id="imagen" class="img-circle"/>
    <b class="caret"></b>
         </a>
```

cuando quiero tomar una imagen según un parámetro lo hago de esta manera, esto es para generar la ruta de la imagen en forma dinamica.

```
  <img th:classappend="${#strings.toLowerCase(nombre)}" th:src="@{${'/images/operadores/' + idOperador + '.png'}}" width="60" height="60"/>
```

Esta es la estructura de las carpetas de mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a definir la ruta de la siguiente forma

```
 <img src="../static/images/roma.jpg" width="1000"
             th:src="@{images/roma.jpg}"/>
```

Y verifica la ruta correcta de las imagenes

Comment: Buenas, lo acabo de probar y no me funciona

Comment: Debes crear la carpeta images dentro de static manualmente

Comment: tampoco me funciona :(

Comment: He editado la pregunta, con otra posible solución, pero verifique que la ruta que yo he colocado se corresponde con la que usted tiene